# Comparing phone numbers in Android

Tags: java, android, string, phone-number

I need to compare two phone numbers to determine if they're from the same sender/receiver. The user may send a message to a contact, and that contact may reply.

The reply usually comes in 
`+[country-code][area-code-if-any][and-then-the-actual-number]` format. For example,
`+94 71 2593276` for a Sri Lankan phone number.

And when the user *sends* a message, he will usually enter in the format (for the above example) `0712593276` (assume he's also in Sri Lanka).

So what I need is, **I need to check if these two numbers are the same.** This app will be used internationally. So I can't just replace the first 2 digits with a 0 (then it will be a problem for countries like the US). Is there any way to do this in Java or Android-specifically?

Thanks.

Comment: Phone numbers don't follow simple rules which apply in every country.  You will need to code cases for each country.

Comment: @PeterLawrey That seems a bit extreme.. :) But it should be possible. Just think of the stock Android messaging app. It will recognize if its the same number whether or not we enter it both ways.

Comment: I imagine it has a lookup table for this. Is there anyway to read the source of or decompile this app?

Comment: i hope it compares the last 10 numbers only

Comment: @PeterLawrey I'm developing the app currently, but I'm not allowed to display the source. Sorry :(

Comment: @droidhot It depends on the country. UK I think has 11 numbers.

Comment: I meant; gain access to the source of the Android Messaging App which does what you want.

Comment: @PeterLawrey Ah... No idea :/

Answer (score 19):

Android has nice PhoneNumberUtils, and i guess your looking for :

```
    public static boolean compare (String a, String b)
```

look in :
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/PhoneNumberUtils.html

using it should look like this :

```
String phone1   
String phone2 

 if (PhoneNumberUtils.compare(phone1, phone2)) {
    //they are the same do whatever you want!
   }
```

Answer (score 11):

`android.telephony.PhoneNumberUtils` class provides almost all necessary functions to deal with phone numbers and standards.

For your case, the solution is `PhoneNumberUtils.compare(Context context, String number1, String number2)` or else `PhoneNumberUtils.compare(String number1, String number2)`.The former one checks a resource to determine whether to use a strict or loose comparison algorithm, thus the better choice in most cases.

```
PhoneNumberUtils.compare("0712593276", "+94712593276") // always true
PhoneNumberUtils.compare("0712593276", "+44712593276") // always true

// true or false depends on the context
PhoneNumberUtils.compare(context, "0712593276", "+94712593276")
```

Take a look at the official [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/PhoneNumberUtils.html). And the [source code](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/telephony/java/android/telephony/PhoneNumberUtils.java).

Answer (score 3):

How about checking if the number is a substring of the receiver's number?

For instance, let's say my Brazilian number is 888-777-666 and yours is 111-222-333.
To call you, from here, I need to dial additional numbers to make international calls. Let's say I need to add 9999 + your_number, resulting in 9999111222333.

If `RawNumber.substring(your_number)` returns `true` I can say that I'm calling you.

Answer (score -1):

just apply your logic to remove () and - 
and follow PhoneNumberUtils