# Comparing contacts on device with the registered number from the server

Tags: android, android-contacts

I want to create a contact list for my application where the numbers on the device has to be compared with the numbers in the database which are used to register for using the application. I have got all the numbers available on the device inside a ArrrayList using the following code.

```
  ArrayList<ContactInfo> phoneNo = new ArrayList<ContactInfo>();
        Cursor phones = getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null,null,null, null);
        while (phones.moveToNext())
        {
          String name=phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME));
          String phoneNumber = phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
          Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), phoneNumber, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
          ContactInfo contact = new ContactInfo(name, phoneNumber);
          phoneNo.add(contact);
        }
        phones.close();
    }

    class ContactInfo{
        String strName;
        String strPhoneNum;
        public ContactInfo(String Name, String PhoneNo) {
            this.strName = Name;
            this.strPhoneNum = PhoneNo;
            // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        }
    }
```

Now I want to compare it with all the contacts in database on the server which were used during app registration. My purpose for doing this is to create a contact list for the application which has only the contact number and names of that users who are using my application. Now how can I compare all these device contacts with the numbers stored in database in the server. Please guide me for the same. I am new to android.

Comment: Try search before post. Read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12282569/comparing-phone-numbers-in-android

Comment: @PankajKumar: I had seen that post but my requirement is bit different from that. Can you please help me with what I have asked ?

Comment: :) What is different. To read contacts from server?? Then contact your server team how they give you the list.

Comment: @PankajKumar I am an individual working on the application. So I have to look into everything.