# Android compare formatted and unformatted phone number

Tags: android, string, number-formatting, phone-number, phonenumberutils

I have two phone numbers. I want to compare them. One is unformatted and one is formatted, for example:
"0501231234", "050-123-1234".

How can I compare them ( `String.equals()` )?

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/q/12282569/247696

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`android.telephony.PhoneNumberUtils`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/PhoneNumberUtils.html) class provides methods to compare phone numbers. The `compare(String a, String b)` method usually suffices, as it will "return true if they're identical enough for caller ID purposes."

Answer (score 0):

You need to strip the one with the "-" and then use **equals**

```
String s1 = "0501231234",s2 = "050-123-1234s";
boolean equal = s1.equals(s2.replaceAll("-", ""));
```

Comment: I did PhoneNumberUtils.compare(formatted, unformatted).